# The style of component A cannot be dynamically modified in the text component. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

When i place component A in the text component, the text color in style is bound. If you change the value of the bound textcolor, the text color of component A cannot be changed. For example, if you wish to change the text color from blue to red. Sample code:

Code in the template:

```
<text>
        <a href="https://huawei.com" style="color: {{textcolor}};" value="click here"></a>
    </text>
     <input type="button" value="Change the text color of component a." onclick="changeColor" />
```

Code in the script:

```
changeColor: function() {
      this.textcolor="red";
    }
```

When component A is placed in the text component, the quick app framework does not support dynamic style changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the dynamic style to the outer text component to achieve the color change effect. The sample code is as follows (see the **red part**):

```
<text style="color: {{textcolor}};">
      <a href="https://huawei.com" value="click here"></a>
</text>
```

**Effect (after tapping the button)**:

[image]

For more details, check:

Quick app documentation: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-Guides/quickapp-whitepaper?ha_source=hms1